# Android Programmatically set AudioEncoder for MediaRecorder

Tags: java, android, android-mediarecorder

My question is: How can I programmatically set the AudioEncoder for MediaRecorder?

I am trying to programmatically set the AudioEncoder by replacing the statically set AAC or AAC_ELD with the int variable mEncode which is manually selected from a list of variables such as:

int  mEncode = 3;
OR
int  mEncode = 5;

When I replace AAC with int variable mEncode with value of 3 or 5 the code will not compile.
I get error message Cannot resolve symbol 'mEncode".

Android documentation shows that:
int AAC Constant Value: 3 (0x00000003)
int AAC_ELD Constant Value: 5 (0x00000005)
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.html

Can anyone help me with the correct code?

Java code:

```
    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(16000);
    mRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(24000);
    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);

    // my current static method set with AAC or AAC_ELD:
    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
    mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);

    // my dynamic method set with int variable mEncode:
    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.mEncode);
```

Comment: what is `mEncode`? if `mEncode` is a variable you defined, you access it just by its name, without qualifying it with `MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder`